# Find and bin difference values, within particular range, between elements in two large vectors (too big for bsxfun)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, optimization, subtraction

Lets say we have vectors `time_a` and `time_b` with ~6 million to 12 million  elements (with different lengths) in ascending order (units of picoseconds)

For example:

```
time_a=[ 72196880 112521880 118581820 122398052 142394088 144797508........6 million more....]

time_b=[81656628 151885536 169269680 424456200 652427880 760435300........12 million more....]
```

In the most time consuming way, we could loop through each element in a `time_a`, subtract each element in `time_b`, and do an if statement to see if the difference is within a particular tmax and tmin.  If it is, we bin it and add it to a histogram, `c`. `c` is divided into `tmin:binsize:tmax`, as you will see, so once we find that our difference is within our range, we add one to the appropriate bin in `c`.

Below is the code I have so far. I think there is a more clever way to do this. Keep in mind, the full vectors are too large to use `bsxfun(@subtract,time_a,time_b')`
that would create a matrix with a lot of columns and rows people. Any clever ideas?

```
function [c, dt, dtEdges] = coincidence4(time_a,time_b,tmin,tmax,binsize)
% round tmin, tmax to a intiger multiple of binsize:
if mod(tmin,binsize)~=0
    tmin=tmin-mod(tmin,binsize)+binsize;
end
if mod(tmax,binsize)~=0
    tmax=tmax-mod(tmax,binsize);
end

dt = tmin:binsize:tmax;
dtEdges = [dt(1)-binsize/2,dt+binsize/2];

c = zeros(1,length(dt));

Na = length(time_a);
Nb = length(time_b);

tic1=tic;

bbMin=1;
for aa = 1:Na
    ta = time_a(aa);
    bb = bbMin;

    while (bb<=Nb)
        tb = time_b(bb);
        d = tb - ta;
        if d < tmin
            bbMin = bb;
            bb = bb+1;
        elseif d > tmax
            bb = Nb+1;
        else

            index = floor((d-dtEdges(1))/(dtEdges(end)-dtEdges(1))*(length(dtEdges)-1)+1);

              c(index)=c(index)+1;
            bb = bb+1;
        end
    end

end
toc(tic1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over just one of the vectors. I mean something along these lines:

```
c = zeros(size(dtEdges));
for aa = 1:Na
    d = time_b - time_a(aa);
    c = c + histc(time_b - time_a(aa), dtEdges);
end
```

Comment: i dont think so, because now we have 6 million vector subtractions instead of scalars.  could you be more specific?  also matrix dimensions dont agree for c=c+histc part

Comment: @user3468979 That's the point: 6e6 vector subtractions of 12e6 elements are more efficient than 72e12 scalar subtractions. As for the size, I'm not sure about your variables, but you could easily initiallize to the appropriate size